# Java mostra "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to HashMap"

Tags: java, hashmap

Estou criando uma classe que através que funciona semelhante ao XPath.

A função funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que nesta parte da linha `(HashMap<String, Object>) test.get("test-map");`, o "eclipse" mostra o seguinte aviso:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to HashMap

Eu acredito que seja uma falha minha, a maneira que estou trabalhando pode estar errada.

Como posso resolver?

```
HashMap<String, Object> test = new HashMap<String, Object>();
test.put("test-string", "abc");
boolean isNull = test.get("test-map")==null;

if(isNull==false){
    HashMap<String, Object> map1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) test.get("test-map");
    System.out.println(map1);
    isNull = map1==null;
}

if(isNull){
    test.put("test-map", new HashMap<String, Object>());
}
String map2 = (String) test.get("test-string");

System.out.println(map2);
```

Answer (score 3):

É uma warning padrão do Java quando se faz *cast* para um tipo que use *generics*.

No Eclipse, você pode remover a warning anotando a declaração da variável com:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, Object> map1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) test.get("test-map");
```

Essa warning acontece porque o compilador sempre garante que código que use *generics* não vai dar `ClassCastException`. Mas como você está convertendo de um `Object`, que ele não tem como saber o que é, ele dá esse aviso dizendo que ele não se garante.

Comment: Então eu já fiz isto, mas eu não acredito que isto seja o melhor.

Comment: Você tem 2 alternativas, ou muda o seu map para em vez de ser de string para object ser de string para hashmap<...> (o que pode não ser possível) ou você garante via lógica de programação que naquele momento que você está dando o cast o que tem lá é realmente um hashmap<...>. E se via lógica está garantido, você pode suprimir a warning.

Comment: Eu concordo, mas o que eu preciso saber é: está é realmente a melhor maneira de fazer isto? Me refiro ao meu código.

Comment: Eu diria que é a única. Por uma escolha de design do java, a informação sobre os argumentos genéricos do HashMap (e qualquer classe que tenha argumentos de tipo) não é preservada em tempo de execução. O ambiente de execução vai saber que é um HashMap, mas não vai saber de que ele é. Por isso ele sempre vai dar warning quando você força um cast para um tipo com generics. 

Existe a opção de declarar a variável como HashMap<?,?>, que é seguro e não dá warnings, mas impede que você use o map.

Comment: Você pode mudar a sua lógica, para que além do Object no map você guarde também um identificador de que tipo de objeto foi guardado, pode ser uma enum. Dessa forma, na hora de retirar o objeto você pode fazer uma checagem e ter certeza do tipo do objeto. E assim pode colocar a anotação de supressão da warning sabendo que está fazendo tudo o que é possível.

Comment: só pra concluir, o meu código está bom, ou eu devo usar `instanceof` ?

Comment: `instanceof` Não resolverá o problema do warning, então é inútil utilizá-lo.

Comment: Com o `instanceof` você pode no máximo testar se o conteúdo do objeto é um `HashMap`, mas não vai conseguir diferenciar entre um `HashMap<A,B>` e um `HashMap<C,D>`, porque essa informação é perdida em tempo de execução. Se você quiser ter certeza absoluta do que tem no map você vai precisar guardar essa informação, por exemplo como uma `enum`, como eu disse. Mas isso amarra mais a arquitetura, para cada tipo novo que você queira colocar você vai ter que adicionar uma entrada nova na enum.

Answer (score 0):

Aplique a seguinte annotation em seu método:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Desse modo o eclipse não sinalizará esse warning.

Comment: É melhor aplicar a anotação apenas à declaração da variável. Se aplicar ao método essa warning vai ser ignorada nele todo, o que pode fazer algum erro escapar.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser eu concordo.

Comment: Uma boa observação.

Answer (score -1):

O Eclipse lança esse aviso porque você está fazendo um cast sem testar o tipo do objeto. para evitar isso, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
if(test.get("test_map") instanceof HashMap<String, Object>){
    HashMap<String, Object> map1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) test.get("test-map");
}
...
```